# Count (distinct) not working for multiple inner join in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have below query with `count(distinct u.uid)` and when I run below query its go on execution state, if I run `count(1)` then I get a result of 236. I don't understand why `count(distinct u.uid)` is not returning a result.

Please note this query is running in other environment of SQL Server not sure why not working in SQL Server 2016 (I am not sure if it is specific to 2016 environment)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct u.uid) AS NOOFROWS 
FROM 
    ABC u
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT uemail 
     FROM ABC 
     GROUP BY uemail 
     HAVING COUNT(1) = 1) AS u2 ON u.uemail = u2.uemail 
INNER JOIN 
    PQR on u.uid = PQR.uid  
INNER JOIN 
    XYZ p ON u.uid = p.uid
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not giving any output"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it goes on execution state and after waiting for 5 mins I have to kill the query manually

Comment: Just don't kill it and wait for the result then. Or give us more information like DDL of the tables and indexes, the execution plan, semantics of the data, etc., if you'd like someone to suggest improvements there.

Comment: @stickybit If I do not kill after 15-20 mins it says connection refused

Answer (score 0):

I'm rewriting the query so I can read it better:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct u.uid) AS NOOFROWS 
FROM ABC u INNER JOIN
     (SELECT uemail
      FROM ABC
      GROUP BY uemail
      HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
     ) u2
     ON u.uemail = u2.uemail INNER JOIN
     PQR 
     ON u.uid = PQR.uid INNER JOIN
     XYZ p
     ON u.uid = p.uid ;
```

I interpreted the question as the query giving `0`, but that is impossible that `COUNT(1)` returns 236 but `COUNT(DISTINCT u.uid)` returns 0 (unless there is a bug in SQL Server).  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` returns `0` only if all the values of `u.uid` are `NULL`.  Because `u.uid` is used in an `INNER JOIN`, it cannot ever be `NULL`.  You *could* get `1`, if all 236 rows had the same value, but you cannot get `0`.

So, perhaps you mean that the query does not return.  If that is the case, then you can use `explain` to see why the two execution plans are different.

Comment: it goes on execution state and after waiting for 5 mins I have to kill the query manually

Answer (score 0):

Check below inner query whether it is returning rows or not ?

```
SELECT uemail
FROM ABC
GROUP BY uemail
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Comment: it is returning and the query is inner join thats why I got 236 final count.